# Break question line in Exam package

Tags: exam

I get the text overlapping on the points.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{setspace,enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep,nolistsep}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep,nolistsep}

%----language
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{romanian}
{\quotedblbase}
{\textquotedblright}
{\guillemotleft}
{\guillemotright}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

%---exam settings
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\textbf{\arabic{question}}}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\textbf{(\thechoice)}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{\thequestion.\arabic{partno}}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{~\thequestion.}}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Rezolvare:}\par\noindent}
\newcommand{\af}[1][{}]{% True / False questions
    \fillin[#1][0.25in]}%

\pointpoints{punct}{puncte}
\bonuspointpoints{punct bonus}{puncte bonus}
\pointformat{\bf(\thepoints)}
\totalformat{Total puncte pentru cerința nr. \thequestion: \totalpoints}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\itshape \bfseries}
\setlength\answerlinelength{4.5cm}
%===========print answer=========================
\noprintanswers
% \printanswers

% ------------- Start Exam ----------------------

\begin{document}
\pointsinrightmargin
%\extrawidth{.3cm}
\marginpointname{ \points}
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{25mm}

\begin{questions}


    \question [2] Cu ce condiție acceptă fata împăratului Roșu să plece cu Harap Alb după ce acesta trece cu bine probele la care îl supune tatăl fetei și cum se termină basmul?

    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice answer 1
        \CorrectChoice answer2
        \choice answer 3
        \choice answer 4
        \choice answer 5
    \end{oneparcheckboxes}


\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

### The output

[image: Overlapping text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what You want?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[right=4cm,
        top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep,nolistsep}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep,nolistsep}

%----language
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{romanian}
{\quotedblbase}
{\textquotedblright}
{\guillemotleft}
{\guillemotright}

%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

%---exam settings
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\textbf{\arabic{question}}}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\textbf{(\thechoice)}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{\thequestion.\arabic{partno}}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{~\thequestion.}}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Rezolvare:}\par\noindent}
\newcommand{\af}[1][{}]{% True / False questions
    \fillin[#1][0.25in]}%

\pointpoints{punct}{puncte}
\bonuspointpoints{punct bonus}{puncte bonus}
\pointformat{\bf(\thepoints)}
\totalformat{Total puncte pentru cerința nr. \thequestion: \totalpoints}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\itshape \bfseries}
\setlength\answerlinelength{4.5cm}
%===========print answer=========================
\noprintanswers
% \printanswers

% ------------- Start Exam ----------------------

\begin{document}
\pointsinrightmargin
%\extrawidth{.3cm}
\marginpointname{ \points}
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{0mm}

\begin{questions}


    \question [2] Cu ce condiție acceptă fata împăratului Roșu să plece cu Harap Alb după ce acesta trece cu bine probele la care îl supune tatăl fetei și cum se termină basmul?

    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice answer 1
        \CorrectChoice answer2
        \choice answer 3
        \choice answer 4
        \choice answer 5
    \end{oneparcheckboxes}


\end{questions}
\end{document}
```